# Installing Native Script with CmD is unresponsive - With Powershell is unrecognised Command

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, nativescript

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

Trying to run this script in CMD as Admin leads to no action

Running this in Powershell as admin leads to this error:

```
+ @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-ob ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-NoProfile' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:24
+ @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-ob ...
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-ExecutionPolicy' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ @powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-ob ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@powershell' can be used only as
an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$powershell'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

I have looked at my environment variables PATH and added the path to my powershell.exe :

```
C:\Users\Riss\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell
```

But still no bueno.

Comment: Remove the `@` before `powershell`. That is a `cmd.exe` thing.

Comment: @lit thats the answer

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

The answer @lit gave is correct

Remove @ before powershell and the script
    `powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object  net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"`

will work in CMD